# Which ways of distribution of Tokens are being used beside ICO/STO?

Tags: ico, airdrop

Assume, I've created my own ERC-20 Token and published it to the Ethereum Blockchain. By doing so I also got access to all of the initially created tokens.

If I'd like to distribute them, the only ways i know would be either to:

- Sell them via an Initial Coin Offering (ICO) or Security Token Offering (STO)
- Gift them directly / indirectly, also called Airdrops.

Which other ways of distribution are commonly used for ethereum Tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the ways you mentioned are the most common ones.

Some other ideas/possibilities:

- Sell them in an open crowdsale contract which is not part of an ICO/STO. The contract might not even have an end date but it may sell tokens indifinitely until no more tokens are for sale - or it keeps minting new ones all the time.
- Distribute them based on some work/effort. Either for on-chain or off-chain actions. For example bounties or contribution to some on-chain effort.
- Distribute based on random other criteria. For example whenever thing X (a transaction of another token, Ether transaction to a certain address, other transaction, ...) happens on-chain you send your tokens.

Comment: Just for clarification, do you mean with open crowdsale contract an Ethereum Contract? If not, what is then the difference to an STO, in case the crowdsale is not unlimited long and don't generate new tokens?

Comment: Yes, an Ethereum contrat. Basically just a regular Crowdsale contract without many of the restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

- Pay bounties men.
- Pay team(support, devs, co-founders..ex).
- Partnership (only if your project awesome ).
- Pay the exchanges.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really another way of distributing your token, but if you're looking to airdrop your token on large scale you can use [Dapple Airdrops](https://www.dappleairdrops.com/) which allows batch transfers of at least 150 addresses at a time. Here is the link to the DApp: https://www.dappleairdrops.com and here is a tutorial on how to use it: https://medium.com/@zenospavlakou/dapple-airdrops-batch-transfer-any-erc20-token-1ff416834525